# How to display Wikipedia pages in my website?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am building my own version of [thewikigame.com](https://www.thewikigame.com/group). It is based on the concept of [Wikiracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikirace). On the website, the developer embeds the Wikipedia pages into his own website, and tracks how many clicks the user makes to reach the target page. I am not sure how he did this. What would be the best way possible to get the HTML + styling to display these pages on my own website?

Comment: hey are you still working on this project ? I'm trying to do the same as well and I'm currently exploring options using the Wikimedia API

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, **you need first** to download the whole content of *enwiki* to your website. And to do this you have to download the dump XML for English Wikipedia from this [mirror](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/), then import that XML to your wiki using one of [these methods](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps).